# How to match Route to any path EXCEPT the base (home) path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've enjoyed using react-router to conditionally render based on location. For example, I have a component that only renders if I am on the home page, like so:

```
<Route
    exact={ true }
    path="/"
    render={ HomeHeroSection }
/>
```

However, because of design requirements, I also have a component that should only be rendered if NOT at the home page/base path. I have only been able to come up with a path-to-regexp pattern that accomplishes this if I name some arbitrary unused parameter, as a sort of wildcard.

```
<Route
    path="/:foo+"
    render={ NavLinks }
/>
```

Is there a better pattern for the `path` prop that I should be using? Or perhaps a better general react-router paradigm? I've considered Switch, among other things, but I'm curious if I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `HomeHeroSection` component to render only on the root route and the `NavLinks` component to render only on any other route, this is the use case for `Switch`. From the [docs on Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch):

> Switch is unique in that it renders a route *exclusively*. In contrast, every  that matches the location renders *inclusively*.

So `Switch` is the right call here.

Here's how you can use it in this case:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ HomeHeroSection }/>
    <Route component={ NavLinks }/>
</Switch>
```

Note that the order of the `Route` components is important here as `Switch` renders the *first* child `Route` that matches the location.

Note that not providing a `path` attribute to a `Route` will cause it to match any route (so these should go last in order). If the location that was used to arrive at the `NavLinks` component matters, you can include the `path` attribute like normal.

**Edit:**

Since the two components do not appear in the same place on the page you can use just a plain `Route` for the `HomeHeroSection` as you have already, and a `Switch` that renders `null` on the root route for the `NavLinks` component. Here's an example:

```
<main>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ HomeHeroSection }/>

    <span>Some other stuff</span>

    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={ null }/>
        <Route component={ NavLinks }/>
    </Switch>
</main>
```

This will render the `NavLinks` component for any route other than the root and will render nothing on the root route.

Comment: `path=component={ Navlinks }`, a typo? Also, I think OP wants something else. What you show here something similar to `NotFound` page logic right? If I understand OP right, the desired functionality is rendering a component in every route other than `/`. So, if I have `/foo`, `/bar` this component should be rendered in all of them except `/`.

Comment: @devserkan it is pretty much the same logic as how you would do a `NotFound` page, but what OP and you have described is just that, unless I am misunderstanding. A component that renders for specific routes and then one that renders for all other routes. The component need not be the whole page. (also yes that was a typo thank you)

Comment: Sort of. I think you both mostly understand what I'm getting at. I guess I should also point out that these components aren't placed as children in the same spot, so that's why the Switch seems odd to me for my use case.

Comment: You can have a switch where the `/` match has a null component, and thus, renders nothing. Only the default case having a specified component.

Comment: @Kroltan that is what I've been toying with, but it seems so weird to me. It seems to me like that sort of usage belongs to the `path` prop, but I can't find any mention of that in the documentation.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah if they're in different places a `Switch` is probably not the way to go. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @mikkelrd, should this component be rendered **in**  every other component that matches every other route? If not, I understood you so wrong.

Comment: `NavLinks` should be rendered where I have put it, for any page that's not the base. On the other hand, `HomeHeroSection` should render where I've put it only if I'm at the base path.

Comment: @mikkelrd is that Edit in the post closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: I didn't get the part "where I put". This is why we are defining routes.

Comment: @HenryWoody, with your last edit, if there is another route, `NavLinks` will not be rendered. Am I wrong?

Comment: @devserkan If you add another `Route`, then, yes, `NavLinks` will not render, but only when the location matches the path for that new `Route`. However if you wanted both `NavLinks` and this new component to render, then they shouldn't both be put in the same `Switch`.

Comment: Ah, how couldn't I think of that! Now, I get it, thank you. The only downside of this logic I think there won't be any `NotFound` component and this is what you said earlier :) "it is pretty much the same logic as how you would do a NotFound page,"

Comment: @devserkan at the time i thought it was the same as implementing a NotFound page, but it is slightly different in that the two components don't really swap for each other since they are in different places. It seems they are unrelated, but happen to render on mutually exclusive routes. However, it still works largely the same except the two components can be in different places.

Comment: Yes, that snippet seems to be the most "straightforward" way to do it. Thank you for adding that edit. But like I said, if there is a way to use the path prop to say "match only this path" or "match paths of this shape", I believe we should also be able to use that prop to reliably say "match NOT this path". I'll go file an issue on the repo.

Comment: Nevermind. The docs for Switch also mention that route params used in this way, basically as a throwaway, is by design. Thanks for the help everybody